# Translating OpenGL 4.5 stuff to OpenGL 4.0 make my program crash

Tags: c++, opengl

I would excuse me if the title is not explicit

I have a little program which print some mesh on screen, the code I use to init and draw is the following :

(Here you have the init code)

```
glGenVertexArrays(1, &VAO);

glCreateBuffers(1, &VerticesVBO);
glCreateBuffers(1, &NormalVBO);
glCreateBuffers(1, &ColorVBO);

glBindVertexArray(VAO);
glNamedBufferStorage(VerticesVBO,vertexData.GetCount() * sizeof(float),&(vertexData[0]), GL_MAP_READ_BIT  | GL_MAP_WRITE_BIT);
glNamedBufferStorage(NormalVBO,normalData.GetCount() * sizeof(float),&(normalData[0]), GL_MAP_READ_BIT  | GL_MAP_WRITE_BIT);
glNamedBufferStorage(ColorVBO,colorData.GetCount() * sizeof(float),&(colorData[0]), GL_MAP_READ_BIT  | GL_MAP_WRITE_BIT);

glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER,VerticesVBO);
glVertexAttribPointer(0, 3, GL_FLOAT, GL_FALSE, 3 * sizeof(float), (void*)0);
glEnableVertexAttribArray(0);

glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER,NormalVBO);
glVertexAttribPointer(1, 3, GL_FLOAT, GL_FALSE, 3 * sizeof(float), (void*)0);
glEnableVertexAttribArray(1);

glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER,ColorVBO);
glVertexAttribPointer(2, 3, GL_FLOAT, GL_FALSE, 3 * sizeof(float), (void*)0);
glEnableVertexAttribArray(2);
```

(and here come the rendering code)

```
    glBindVertexArray(VAO);
    if(showMesh && noLight.IsLinked() && light.IsLinked()){
        OpenGLProgram&  prog = (showLight)? light : noLight;
        prog.Bind();
        if(showLight)prog.SetVec3("viewPos",viewPosition.x,viewPosition.y,viewPosition.z);
        prog.SetMat4("ViewMatrix", viewMatrix);
        prog.SetMat4("ProjectionMatrix", projectionMatrix);
        prog.SetMat4("ModelMatrix", transform.GetModelMatrice());
        glDrawArrays(((prog.ContainTCS()) ? GL_PATCHES : GL_TRIANGLES), 0, SurfaceCount);
    }
```

However since this OpenGL code is only compatible with OpenGL 4.5 I have made some change to ensure a compatibility with OpenGL 4.0 :
(Here is how I change the init code)

```
glGenVertexArrays(1, &VAO);
glGenBuffers(1, &VerticesVBO);
glGenBuffers(1, &NormalVBO);
glGenBuffers(1, &ColorVBO);

glBindVertexArray(VAO);
glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER,VerticesVBO);
glBufferSubData(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER,0,vertexData.GetCount() * sizeof(float),&(vertexData[0]));
glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER,NormalVBO);
glBufferSubData(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER,0,normalData.GetCount() * sizeof(float),&(normalData[0]));
glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER,ColorVBO);
glBufferSubData(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER,0,colorData.GetCount() * sizeof(float),&(colorData[0]));

glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER,VerticesVBO);
glVertexAttribPointer(0, 3, GL_FLOAT, GL_FALSE, 3 * sizeof(float), (void*)0);
glEnableVertexAttribArray(0);

glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER,NormalVBO);
glVertexAttribPointer(1, 3, GL_FLOAT, GL_FALSE, 3 * sizeof(float), (void*)0);
glEnableVertexAttribArray(1);

glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER,ColorVBO);
glVertexAttribPointer(2, 3, GL_FLOAT, GL_FALSE, 3 * sizeof(float), (void*)0);
glEnableVertexAttribArray(2);
```

I have not changed the draw code. The probleme is, when using the OpenGL 4.5 init code, everythings is working, however when using the 4.0, code crash at first loop after the glDrawArrays(...) . I have no idea if the probleme is related to OpenGL but since it work perfectly with my 4.5 code ...

Someone can help me ? Thanks

Comment: If I comment the glDrawArrays(...) while using the OpenGL 4.0 code it work (nothing is draw but it don't crash)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to use [`glBufferData`](https://www.khronos.org/registry/OpenGL-Refpages/gl4/html/glBufferData.xhtml) instead of [`glBufferSubData`](https://www.khronos.org/registry/OpenGL-Refpages/gl4/html/glBufferSubData.xhtml) because it doesn't allocate space in gpu